# Writing values with multiple tags into influxDB (with python)

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

I’m writing values (floats) to an Influx database with (using DataFrameClient), along with two tags: an ID and a timestamp

```
def write_to_influx(ID, value):
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[value],index=pandas.date_range(start=datetime.utcnow(), periods=1, freq='S'), columns=['value'])
    client.write_points(df, dataPointID, database="mydb")
```

In my loop it happens that I write to the same db consecutively multiple times, like this:

```
while True:

    value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4,value_5 = some_calculation(x,y,z)

    write_to_influx(value_1, ID_1)
    write_to_influx(value_2, ID_2)
    write_to_influx(value_3, ID_3)
    write_to_influx(value_4, ID_4)
    write_to_influx(value_5, ID_5)
```

I was told that it's possible to batch these write request into one, which would reduce load on Influx.

I stole the `write_to_influx` method from another script when actually I have problems grasping this. In the docs it says

```
write_points(points, time_precision=None, database=None, retention_policy=None, tags=None, batch_size=None, protocol=u'json', consistency=None)
```

*Parameters:
points (list of dictionaries, each dictionary represents a point) – the list of points to be written in the database*

But with `write_to_influx(value_1, ID_1)`, there is not just a dictionary, but an datapoint ID passed.

Analog to the method already applied and the docu description… If I would like to write multiple values to multiple datapoint IDs, should I pass a list of dictionaries AND a list of datapointIDs ? Because that does not seem to work:

```
def write_values_to_influx(ID_list, value_list):

    indexes=pandas.date_range(start=datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC), periods=1, freq='S')

    dict_list=[]
    for value in value_list:
        df_new= pandas.DataFrame(data=[value],index=indexes)
        dict_list.append(df_new)

    client.write_points(dict_list, ID_list, database="mydb")
```

while True:

```
value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4,value_5 = some_calculation(x,y,z)

ID_list=[ID_1,ID_2,ID_3,ID_4,ID_5]
value_list=[value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4,value_5]

write_values_to_influx(ID_list, value_list)
```

Returns the error:

```
File "/vdp/base_functions.py", line 249, in write_values_to_influx
xyz@crVB    |     client.write_points(dict_list, ID_list, database="mydb")
xyz@crVB    |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/_dataframe_client.py", line 123, in write_points
xyz@crVB    |     numeric_precision=numeric_precision)
xyz@crVB    |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/_dataframe_client.py", line 282, in _convert_dataframe_to_lines
xyz@crVB    |     dataframe = dataframe.dropna(how='all').copy()
```

**My question:
How can I write multiple entries at once (to the same db)? Is write_points the write method? And the DataFrameClient?**

Comment: Question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: difficult, since it would require the setup of an influxdb, right?

Comment: No. What is pd, ZWP? What is returned by updateValues()? Where is coming that attribute dropna? .... are these questions clear from your description. Sorry, no. Of course don't comment my questions here, but make better description/code, which I can copy paste into my editor.

Comment: I rewrote the question, thanks for your input!

Comment: Keep in mind that influx requires your points in a specific format. E. g. every point must have a 'time' field.
You'd have to create a valid dict for each point. Afterwards put this dicts in a list and pass them to the write_points method provided by the influx client.

Answer (score 2):

https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html

> write_points(points, time_precision=None, database=None, retention_policy=None, tags=None, batch_size=None, protocol=u'json', consistency=None)
>
> Parameters:
>   points (list of dictionaries, each dictionary represents a point) – the list of points to be written in the database

You are using right function `client.write_points`, just send list of datapoints.

Comment: FYI there is a bounty on this now, really need to get this working :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
write_api.write(bucket=bucket, record=points)
```

in [influxdb 2.0 for python client](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python).